# Is this application of the chain rule for differentials correct?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives

Let $A : M \to N$ and $B : N \to L$ be differentiable maps of manifolds. Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to M$ be a path. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(B(A(\gamma(t)))\right) \bigg|_{t=0} &=& dB_{A(\gamma(0))} \left(\frac{d}{dt}(A(\gamma(t)))\bigg|_{t=0}\right)\\
&=& dB_{A(\gamma(0))} dA_{\gamma(0)} \gamma^\prime(0)
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. You can also see it as $${\rm d}(B \circ A)_{\gamma(0)}(\gamma'(0)) = {\rm d}B_{A(\gamma(0))}\circ {\rm d}A_{\gamma(0)}(\gamma'(0)).$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$